# Where is the error? Determining why a proof is incorrect.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Why is the following proof incorrect?

I have tried to find out why for a few  hours...

[aproof http://forosdelecuador.com/proof.png](http://forosdelecuador.com/proof.png)

The answer is:
We aren't really proving the conclusion of each case is valid for the other case.
Consider the case assumptions for each case to define the real boundaries for x.

Comment: Your proof should be ok.

Comment: The line *Then we have proven both* $0<x$ *and* $x<6$ is not justified. You’ve proved that $x<6$ if $x-3\ge 0$ and that $0<x$ if $x-3<0$. You still have to prove that $0<x$ if $x-3\ge 0$ and that $x<6$ if $x-3<0$. These are easy, but your argument isn’t correct without them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From case 1 and case 2, you are using the following logic:

If $x<6$ or $0 < x$, then $0<x<6$.

What you need to do is to deduce from case 1:
If $x-3 \ge 0$ then $3 \le x < 6$.
Similarly for case 2.  Then you should use the logic:

If $3 \le x<6$ or $0< x < 3$, then $0<x<6$.

Comment: What do you recommend to prove those two other possibilities? Two new cases?

or two sub proofs by cases for each outer case

Comment: I would simply add at the end of case 1 that we also have $x \ge 3$ (because it is a hypothesis), and hence $3 \le x < 6$.  Similarly for case 2.

Comment: But you do understand that each part of the proof has to stand by itself.  If you have a statement "If $x<6$ or $0<x$, then $0<x<6$", then this line of the proof is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely understand why that is wrong.